# Arduino Due with Logitech F710 gamepad

Tags: arduino-due, joystick

I'm having Arduino Due board and Logitech F710 Wireless Gamepad. I have connected the receiver dongle to native port of Due board via OTG cable.

As the native usb host library supports only keyboard and mouse,
pease help me with correct library for connecting my gamepad with Due board **without** usb_host_shield as I have budget constraint and space constraint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is unclear what you are wanting to do ... what are the two things that you want to connect together?

Comment: Logitech F710 Wireless Gamepad -> USB OTG -> Arduino Due (Native Port)

Comment: here is a project that may get you started ... https://tutorial.cytron.io/2019/05/01/interfacing-logitech-wireless-gamepad-f710-using-arduino/

Comment: This is done with the help of external usb shield. I want to make use of the usbhost built-in Due board. Default it only supports keyboard and mous. I want to know how to extend that to Logitech f710 Gamepad.

Comment: that library shows you how to talk to the gamepad ... you will have to adapt the code to your device